# Redux saga: compose sagas

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a `networkSaga`, where I fetch posts, add and remove likes. After I added or removed a like, I need to call `getPosts` to update the number of likes.

In redux-thunk, I'll simply call `dispatch(getPosts())` after I added or removed the like. Since, I'm new to sagas, I'm concerned, how should it be done?

```
import { all, call, fork, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { NetworkActionTypes } from './types';
import { apiCaller } from '../../utils/apiCaller';
import { onSuccess, onFailure } from '../../utils/actionCreators';

function* getPosts(action): Generator {
  try {
    const res = yield call(apiCaller, action.meta.method, action.meta.route, action.meta.data);

    yield put(onSuccess(NetworkActionTypes.GET_POSTS_SUCCESS, res));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(onFailure(NetworkActionTypes.GET_POSTS_ERROR, err));
  }
}

function* addLike(action): Generator {
  try {
    const res = yield call(apiCaller, action.meta.method, action.meta.route, action.meta.data);

    yield put(onSuccess(NetworkActionTypes.ADD_LIKE_SUCCESS, res));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(onFailure(NetworkActionTypes.ADD_LIKE_ERROR, err));
  }
}

function* removeLike(action): Generator {
  try {
    const res = yield call(apiCaller, action.meta.method, action.meta.route, action.meta.data);

    yield put(onSuccess(NetworkActionTypes.REMOVE_LIKE_SUCCESS, res));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(onFailure(NetworkActionTypes.REMOVE_LIKE_ERROR, err));
  }
}

/**
 * @desc Watches every specified action and runs effect method and passes action args to it
 */
function* watchFetchRequest(): Generator {
  yield takeEvery(NetworkActionTypes.GET_POSTS, getPosts);
  yield takeEvery(NetworkActionTypes.ADD_LIKE, addLike);
  yield takeEvery(NetworkActionTypes.REMOVE_LIKE, removeLike);
}

/**
 * @desc saga init, forks in effects, other sagas
 */
export function* networkSaga() {
  yield all([fork(watchFetchRequest)]);
}
```

The question may sound foolish, but I'll be grateful if you point me to the solution. Thanks!

Comment: so basically you want to call again a generator function after you get success fthe current one right?

Comment: @PrabhatMishra Yeah, right after I success `addLike` I need to call `getPosts`

Answer (score 0):

you can do by `yield getPosts(action json you have to pass here)` once you receive the success from `add/remove` api.

But i suggest better to trigger a action from the component which does that for you,
This will help you to keep all the generator functions re-usable and testable.